# Sorting HTML table using tablesorter jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I converted the json from cartodb to HTML table using javascript. Now i am trying to use the Table sorter Jquery Plugin for making into a sortable tables. I used the Tablesorter in my code but i couldnot able to get any sorting in the result.Below is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <style>
        canvas {
            height: 400px;
            margin: 5px;
            width: 1500px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="excelDataTable">
    </div>


    <script>
        $(function () {
                    data2 = "carto"; 
                    json_link = 'http://development.localhost.lan:8080/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT * FROM ' + data2;
                    $.getJSON(json_link, function (result) { 
                        var th_main = "";
                        for (var e in result['fields']) {
                            th_main = th_main + '<th>' + e + '</th>';
                        }
                        var table_header = '<thead>' +
                                  '<tr>' +
                                    th_main +
                                 '</tr>' +
                              '</thead>';
                        var body_main = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < result['rows'].length; i++) {
                            var tr = "<tr>";
                            for (var ele in result['rows'][i]) {
                                tr = tr + '<td>' + result['rows'][i][ele] + '</td>';
                            }
                            var tr = tr + "</tr>";
                            body_main = body_main + tr;
                        }
                        var table_body = '<tbody>' + body_main + '</tbody>';
                        var table = "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-striped'>" + table_header + table_body + "</table>";
                        $("#excelDataTable").html(table);
                        $(document).ready(function() { 
                            $("#excelDataTable").tablesorter(); 
                        } 
                                );



        });
    }  
                       }
            );
        });

</script>


</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that might be causing your issue:

First, there is an error in your link to `jQuery UI` - you're missing the `http:`.

Second, your script has a syntax error on line 57 - there is an extra `}`.

If you check the browser console it will tell you about these things.

Finally, you need to call `.tablesorter()` like so (see my final comment for more details):

`$("#excelDataTable > table").tablesorter();`

Comment: I had added the missing http: and extra } was also removed. But still i can get the table displayed in the browser but not with the sorting functionalities.

Comment: What does it do now?  Are there any messages on the console?  Perhaps you could edit the post with a sample of the JSON returned by your AJAX call.

Comment: No errors were displayed in the console. I had uploaded my resulting table in the browser as a snapshot.

Comment: Two further things: you have an error in one of your stylesheet URLs.  And - and this is the problem - you're calling `.tablesorter()` on the ID of the containing `div` element and not on the `table` element.  (As an aside, by merely appending the table name to the AJAX API query you're open to an SQL injection attack.)